# Passing Textfield Value to Label in another view Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am a newbie in iphone development and Xcode.
and i am having a hard time running a simple demo app for passing my textfield text from one view to the label in another view programmatically....
And i DONT know where i am going wrong [Even did NSLOG to check the string coming...it says Null :( ]

See if you guys can help me find where i am lacking the code??
Thanks in advance!

Here is the thing i did:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>{
    NSString *str;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str;

@end
```

---

ViewController.m ***

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "nextViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize str;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UITextField *txt =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 30)];
    txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect ;
    txt.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:txt];


    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(80, 80, 200, 30);
    [btn setTitle:@"Press" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.str = [textField text];
    return YES;
}

-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender{



    nextViewController *next =[[nextViewController alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];

}
```

---

nextViewController.h ***

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface nextViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString *str;
}
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str;

@end
```

---

nextViewController.m ***

---

```
#import "nextViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface nextViewController ()

@end

@implementation nextViewController
@synthesize str;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl.frame=CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 30);
    ViewController *VC =[[ViewController alloc]init];
    lbl.text=VC.str;`enter code here`

    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: FYI: `**HELP**` doesn't justify the horrible sin of misusing the `xcode` tag.

Comment: @H2CO3 hahahaha...okay....Sorry its my first question ever on stack overflow....dont now the FORMAT for asking help here...Peace Bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the `nextViewController`'s property of `str` to the string that you'd like to set it to.

```
-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender{
    nextViewController *next =[[nextViewController alloc]init];
    if (self.str)
        next.str = self.str;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
}
```

Also, you are creating a new instance of the ViewController for no apparent reason. Just use the following which sets the string passed to the nextViewController to the label:

```
lbl.text = self.str;
```

Comment: Lagging... how is it lagging?

Answer (score 0):

your error is here

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl.frame=CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 30);
    ViewController *VC =[[ViewController alloc]init];
    lbl.text=VC.str;`enter code here`

    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

you are creating a new instance of ViewController (hence no valid value in str).

you should set the str from viewcontroller to nextviewcontroller here:

```
-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender{
    nextViewController *next =[[nextViewController alloc]init];
    next.str = [textField text];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
}
```

and change the viewdidlog from nextviewcontroller to

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl.frame=CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 30);
    lbl.text=self.str;
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: tried what you guys have mentioned...still not working....and i have tried them already...thats my problem. not being able to figure out the loop hole. :'(

Comment: I changed the answer. Just try to set next.str to textfield.text directly. And remove the str from @interface nextViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString *str;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the "btn" function like so:

```
-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender{
    nextViewController *next =[[nextViewController alloc]init];

    next.str = self.str; //<--- Add this.

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: yeah tried it ...but brother it is not working either....the code runs without any error but the next view remains blank ...without the label.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link helpful for you

http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/5/unwind-segues